# How can I get my jQuery Menu to be at the very (VERY) top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've got a jQuery menu on my page, and it's working great (thanks to the people who helped me on my last post), but it's floating about 15px (by my very rudimentary calculations) from the top of the page, and I want it to sit at the very very top if possible.

EDIT:  It floats 10px down in chrome and firefox

Here's a couple screenshots of what's going on

[image]

[image]

Here's my css for the menu bar, so you can see what's going on:

```
#menu{
    height:30px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu > li{
    float:left;
}

#menu > li > ul > li{
position:relative;
width:auto;
}

#file-menu{
width:75px;
}

#applications-menu{
width:160px;
}
```

Comment: Whoa! I downloaded one, and that definitely did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your body probably has a margin or padding set to it.

You should get into a habit of using a `CSS Reset` (which resets all styles to be consistent [*as they can*] across browsers)

Include this file before all other CSS style sheets you have, it should resolve your issues.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.10.3/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
```

Alternatively, you can just add the css:

```
body{margin:0; padding:0} /* At the very top of your CSS sheet */
```

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of these before.  I swear, I've learned more about web design in the past two days than in the rest of my life.  Thanks so much! I'll accept this when I'm allowed to accept an answer.

Comment: You may also want to checkout http://html5boilerplate.com/ (This is a basic barebone HTML & CSS project, which is completely reset, ready for you to code on *(In HTML5)*!)

Comment: I saw Boilerplate yesterday for the first time.  It really is quite amazing.  I'll definitely be using it for my personal projects.

Comment: Keep in mind there are performance impacts of using a CSS Reset. More data to download, much more CSS for the browser to parse & override, and a lot more work to add back default stylings.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Why would he want negative values?

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This will remove the padding or margin that a browser adds in with default options.

Read more about [CSS Resetting here.](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following.

```
* { padding:0px;margin:0px;outline:0px }
```

In most of my designs. By using * you are applying the styles to everything. Then, if you need some of the built in padding/margins later, you can easily add them. Makes styling things much more customizable.

Goodluck.